# PayPal NVP API not working in Live environment

Tags: paypal

I have integrated PayPal to a custom website. Used Express Checkout with NVP API. Embedded the Live credentials in the code and hosted it on a Data Centre. Now, with the Live Credentials, the PayPal API works perfectly in Localhost. However, the same fails in the Live Server. There is no error code that is displayed. All that is shown is

> SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: Short Error Message: Error Code: Error Severity Code: Array ( )

No Other details.

Anyone with a similar issue? Where PayPal is working fine on Localhost but not on the Live Server even though both the environments are similar and are using PayPal Live Credentials.

Answer (score 1):

What endpoint are you using? Make sure it's a Live API